# Facebook login com Ionic

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic, facebook, oauth

Estou tentando desenvolver um aplicativo com Ionic que integre com o facebook, entretanto estou com alguns problemas. Vi já outras discussões parecidas mas sem resposta ou solução. 
O problema é o seguinte: configurei meu aplicativo no https://developers.facebook.com e segui o passo-a-passo que o próprio facebook provém. Além disso, usei como base um projeto no github (https://github.com/chanusukarno/Angular-Ionic-OAuth) que faz a integração e troquei apenas o APP ID. Até aí beleza.

Em seguida configurei meu IP local (IP-LOCAL:8100) na configuração de Valid OAuth redirect URIs no facebook.

A questão é que, localmente funciona, mas se buildo no celular não funciona a integração e aparece a seguinte mensagem: 'can't load url the domain of this url isn't included in the app's domains'.

Tentei configurar com essa URL mas não tive sucesso também: www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.htm

Preciso saber como faço a configuração para funcionar no dispotivo.

Comment: Também estou com o mesmo problema, você conseguiu solucionar?

Comment: Na verdade, não tentei mais. Mas acho que uma tentativa válida seria subir o apk na play store e linkar o android package name nas configurações do facebook.

Comment: amigo verifique se no seu arquivo config.xml as configurações:
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />