# Problema com login do faceboo no Ionic

Tags: ionic, facebook-javascript-sdk

Estou desenvolvendo uma integração para uma aplicação móvel com o facebook e meu problema é identico ao desse tópico:
[https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/206699/facebook-login-com-ionic#*=*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/206699/facebook-login-com-ionic#_=_)

Alguem já passou por situação parecida?

Comment: Poderia informar qual endereço de *IP* você esta usando ?

Comment: No meu ambiente de desenvolvimento eu coloquei localhost:8100. Fiz o mesmo na configuração da minha aplicação no facebook, na parte de definir o domínio. Outra coisa que observei é que quando rodo no browser o parametro domain vai com localhost e quando rodo no celular esse valor vai vazio.

Comment: Certo, veja o que acontece é que ao acessar pelo *Dispositivo Móvel* creio que não será mais `localhost` e sim o *Endereço de IP* da rede local em que o dispositivo móvel está conectado. Exemplo: *192.168.0.20*, você tem que ir nas configurações de rede do celular e descobrir qual é o endereço e configurar no *Facebook*.

Comment: Você fala pra colocar o ip do cel no domínio da aplicação no facebook?

Comment: Sim, faça esse teste.

Comment: Eu fiz e aconteceu a mesma coisa.